# FlatList stays blank after getting data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, react-native-flatlist

```
export class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      searchValue: "",
    };
  }
  updateSearch = (value) => {
    this.setState({ searchValue: value });
    if (value.trim() !== "") {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/products/search?apiKey=1234&query=${value}&number=100`
        )
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({ data: res.data });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response.data);
        });
    } else {
      setState({ data: [] });
    }
}}

  render() {
    const {
      data,
      searchValue,
    } = this.state;


    return (
          <SearchBar
            placeholder="Search Food..."
            onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
            value={searchValue}
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.data}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <Text>{item.products.title}</Text>
                      )}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
```

Hey everyone, I'm trying to show the products of the API of Spoonacular in the Flatlist by searching in the SearchBar, no error are shown when I run the code, but the Flatlist just stays blank, what is wrong with it?

Link to documentation of the Database: https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Search-Grocery-Products

Comment: How is `updateSearch` being called in `SearchBar`?

Comment: Do you have successful GET requests to actually populate your state?

Comment: put a console before setState to see if the data is fetched correctly: `console.log(res.data);`

Comment: @vuongvu, I did what you said, and the data is fetched correctly. Example of an object:  `Object {
      "id": 199730,
      "image": "https://spoonacular.com/productImages/199730-312x231.jpg",
      "imageType": "jpg",
      "title": "Manischewitz Original Chicken Roasters Seasoned Coating Mix with Bag, 3 oz, (Pack of 6)",
    },`

Comment: the example object doesn't have `products` key, so this `<Text>{item.products.title}</Text>` should be `<Text>{item.title}</Text>`?

Comment: try console.log(data) inside render()

Comment: @vuongvu I tried that and it still doesn't work

Comment: try  <FlatList data={[{title: 'test1'}, {title: ''test2}]} renderItem={() => (
                  <Text>test</Text>
                      )}, if its still not working, consider something wrong with FlatList

Comment: @Iam, I tried, and the FlatList works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response data shape is

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 192386,
            "title": "Pizza Buddy: Frozen Pizza Dough, 16 Oz",
            "imageType": "jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 27693,
            "title": "Uno Pizza",
            "imageType": "jpg"
        }
    ],
    "totalProducts": 1258,
    "type": "product",
    "offset": 0,
    "number": 2
}
```

`products` is the array that should be passed to the flatlist.

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data.products} // <-- pass the products array from state
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Text>{item.title}</Text> // <-- it is just item.title
  )}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

This would require `this.state.data` to be an object though, so it may be better to only update state with the `products` data.

```
updateSearch = (value) => {
  this.setState({ searchValue: value });
  if (value.trim() !== "") {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/products/search?apiKey=1234&query=${value}&number=100`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data.products });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      });
  } else {
    setState({ data: [] });
  }
}}
```

Then pass as usual

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Text>{item.title}</Text> // <-- it is just item.title
  )}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Comment: I tried your example and it gives me the following error: `undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.data.products')`

Comment: @PiersalvoMigliore Yeah, I realized that would happen after I walked away. Updated my answer, please check again.